# Creating region column from state list & region list to update df columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hey I'm trying to create a column region in a data frame using a list of 2 letter state identifiers and a regions list. Here is what I have so far. I'm having an issue with the region column being overwritten each by the last column update statement. When I separate the region column into column "South" "north" ect I can get the results but I need them all in one column

```
east = [
'CT',
'MA',
'ME',
'NH',
'NJ',
'NY',
'PA',
'RI',
'VT'
]
midwest = [
'IA',
'IL',
'IN',
'KS',
'MI',
'MN',
'MO',
'ND',
'NE',
'OH',
'SD',
'WI'
]
south = [
'AL',
'AR',
'DC',
'DE',
'FL',
'GA',
'KY',
'LA',
'MD',
'MS',
'NC',
'OK',
'SC',
'TN',
'TX',
'VA',
'WV'
]
west = [
'AK',
'AZ',
'CA',
'CO',
'HI',
'ID',
'MT',
'NM',
'NV',
'OR',
'UT',
'WA',
'WY'

]
```

```
broke["Region"] = np.where(broke["state"].isin(east), "East", np.NaN) 
broke["Region"] = np.where(broke['state'].isin(midwest), "Midwest", np.NaN) 
broke["Region"] = np.where(broke["state"].isin(south), "South", np.NaN)
broke["Region"] = np.where(broke["state"].isin(west), "West", np.NaN)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I'm still learning (slowly)
It seems that regions is being overwritten through each execution.
Thanks.

Comment: Each one of those np.where undoes what the previous line did.  Only the first should have `np.nan`  The rest should have `broke['state']` as the final part of the statement.

Comment: @Chris changed to broke["region"] and everything's working as intended. I knew it was something simple. thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Chris solution works nicely...

Another way would be using apply-lambda where you can have multiple condition inside a single loop, instead of have them run multiple times;

```
broke["Region"] = broke["state"].apply(lambda x: "East" if x in east else
                                       ("Midwest" if x in midwest else
                                        ("South" if x in south else
                                         ("West" if x in west else np.nan))))
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Thanks it seems like that would work as well.